# epoch nanoseconds to normal time

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, epoch

i have a data as

```
name        time
0   acn  1530677359000000000
1   acn  1530677363000000000 
2   acn  1530681023000000000 
3   acn  1530681053000000000 
4   acn  1530681531000000000 
5   acn  1530681561000000000
```

So I would like to change the `time` column to `datetime` format.

I tried doing this by executing:

`df['time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`

but it gives improper output as :

> Out[70]:
>     0    2078-09-01 09:55:28.826007552
>     1    2078-10-17 17:02:08.826007552
>     2    2194-10-10 19:42:08.826007552
>     3    2195-09-23 01:02:08.826007552
>     4    2210-11-16 10:48:48.826007552
>     5    2211-10-29 16:08:48.826007552

I am on python 2.7. kindly take a look.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(1530677359000000000, unit='ns')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorised, you can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit='ns'`.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')

print(df)

  name                 time            datetime
0  acn  1530677359000000000 2018-07-04 04:09:19
1  acn  1530677363000000000 2018-07-04 04:09:23
2  acn  1530681023000000000 2018-07-04 05:10:23
3  acn  1530681053000000000 2018-07-04 05:10:53
4  acn  1530681531000000000 2018-07-04 05:18:51
5  acn  1530681561000000000 2018-07-04 05:19:21
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

df.time = df.time.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1e9))
```